# Silverlight 4 - Get Datagrid 'Desired' width space permitting

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that has for instance 5 columns. The Datagrid is within a Grid that is not wide enough (ie that does not allow all the Datagrid  columns to show, for instance 3 columns and a horizontal scrollbar).

I would like to be able to work out the size that the Datagrid *would be* in the situation that there IS enough space and hence no scrollbars. Its like the 'scrollable' area I suppose, ie the full extreme of the horizontal scrollbar.

This is so that I can add a gridsplitter to the grid (in the a second column to the right) that is restricted to go only to the width of the DataGrid and no more.

I hope this makes some sense, any thoughts greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using [DataGrid.FrozenColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of DataGrid  may help you to archive the desire behavior.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and while this property is useful and I have learned something, I'm not sure it answers my problem of trying to calculate the DataGrids width if all columns were visible